# socket.io multiple line message issue

Tags: node.js, socket.io

We are using socket.io@1.3.5 and Socket.IO-Client-Swift to implement a chat application. Everything works okay when a one line message is send. socket.io-parser parses the packet and process it.

[image: one line message]

```
  engine handling "POST" http request "/socket.io/?transport=polling&sid=D4hHosMaFHKF2xZAAAAA" +0ms
  engine setting new request for existing client +1ms!
  engine:polling received "20:42["message","test"]" +0ms
  engine:socket packet +0ms
  socket.io-parser decoded 2["message","test"] as {"type":2,"nsp":"/","data":["message","test"]} +8.2m
  socket.io:socket got packet {"type":2,"nsp":"/","data":["message","test"]} +6m
  socket.io:socket emitting event ["message","test"] +0ms
```

But when I try to send a two line message, it fails to decode it;

[image: two line message]

```
  engine handling "POST" http request "/socket.io/?transport=polling&sid=D4hHosMaFHKF2xZAAAAA" +0ms
  engine setting new request for existing client +0ms
  engine:polling received "27:42["message","test2
test3"]" +1ms
  engine:socket packet +0ms
  socket.io:client no socket for namespace undefined +1m
```

What would be a possible solution for the issue?

Thank you

**Edit:**

I trim the text that I get from the input box if it is more than 255 chars

> ```
> if (text.length > 255) { // trim the text longer than 255
>     text = [text substringToIndex:255];
> }
> ```

And then I emit it with a "message" event;

```
[_socket emit:@"message" withItems:@[text]];
```

It seems in the NSLog as below;

```
2015-05-23 23:36:43.580 TestApp[383:3300397] Text: test3
test4
```

I am not removing new line or any other special characters (which I should maybe)

**Edit 2:**

I've checked my old configuration Socket V0.9 and it looks line client sends the message as "test1\ntest2", I am not sure if the issue belongs the client or the server. Is it related with the header content-type?

Comment: Please show the code you use for getting what the user types and then for sending the message.

Answer (score 1):

Issue solved by adding "\r\n" characters manually.

Obviously old implementation that I am using (https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc) was doing that automatically. But the new implementation (https://github.com/nuclearace/Socket.IO-Client-Swift) that have to be done in your code.